# SetInterval reset on swipe

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, setinterval, hammer.js

So I'm trying to add a progress bar to the "Superslides" slider. I've used setInverval to trigger this when a slide finishes animating and for the most part it works.

I also added a little bit that resets the interval if someone clicks one of the links on the slider (next slide, prev, or pagination) and that also works however the slider has touch support using hammer.js and when I try to do the same thing after a swipe event it doesn't seem to reset properly. It resets the progess bar's width back to 0 but the interval continues despite trying to clear it.

I'm probably doing something fairly stupid but I've been scratching my head for a while so I thought I'd ask what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).on('animated.slides', function() {
      var progressBar = $('#progress-bar');
      width = 0;

      progressBar.width(width);

      var interval = setInterval(function() {

          width += 1;

          progressBar.css('width', width + '%');

          if (width >= 100) {
              clearInterval(interval);
          }

         //Trying to reset on swipe (I've also tried putting this below outside of interval

         Hammer($slides[0]).on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {
         width = 0;
          clearInterval(interval); 

        });


      }, 160);

      //reset on anchor click
      $("#slides a").click(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);

      });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved the issue myself. The slider's implementation uses $slides as a variable for "#slider" and then uses that to trigger the swipe animations. I copied and pasted this into my interval function as is. When I used the id rather than the variable it seems to have worked.